# Where Can I Find Details On The <ivy-report> XML Format?

Tags: xslt, ivy

I need to customize the dependency report from Ivy, and am trying to find more details on the format of the XML file that is the data source for any report.

I have found the [Ivy Report](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/report.html) documentation, and have easily provided my custom XSL template to generate the report. Indeed, my report works fine.

But, I want to have a better understanding about the expected format of this file. Most of the tags and attributes are obvious, but there are some that I am just making assumptions about.

Is there a schema for this report file? Or some place that has an explanation of the various attributes?

Comment: No idea, but have you seen the artifactreport task? This might prove more useful for custom reporting http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactreport.html

Comment: No, @MarkO'Connor, I had not seen the artifactreport report. It does not look like this report has information about dependencies: it is focused on artifacts.  But, even this XML file does not have any documentation on this various tags and attributes? It is looking like they just assume that the meaning is obvious...